# How can I transition from a circle/rounded rectangle to a rectangle in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, transition

In the app I am trying to build I have a scrollview with circles. When the user taps a circle it should smoothly transition to a full screen rectangle.

For simplicity reasons we will only be focussing on trying to transition from a small circle to a full screen rectangle.

**Step 1: Check for Animatable**

With the following code we can animate between a circle and a larger rectangle. Proving that both the `RoundedRectangle()` view and `frame` view modifier are both animatable.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cornerRadius = 60.0
    @State private var size = 100.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
                .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        .animation(.linear, value: cornerRadius)
        .animation(.linear, value: size)
        .onTapGesture {
            cornerRadius = cornerRadius == 0.0 ? 60.0 : 0.0
            size = size == 100.0 ? 300.0 : 100.0
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the effect I am after for transitioning between views.

**Step 2: Transition between Views**

Here is where things get complicated. We have two different views the compact and the full screen version. For clarity I made the compact version orange and the full screen version red and I refer to them as such.

We remove the animatable properties from our earlier example and exchange it with a isFullScreen property that switches between true and false. With `matchedGeometryEffect` we can match the size and frame. To my knowledge SwiftUI should now have all the building blocks to interpolate between the two views and transition them smoothly. However this turns out to be not the case.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var namespace
    
    @State private var isFullScreen = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if !isFullScreen {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 60.0)
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "item", in: namespace)
                    .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
            } else {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0.0)
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "item", in: namespace)
                    .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        .animation(.linear, value: isFullScreen)
        .onTapGesture {
            isFullScreen.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

It appears by the fade animation and ghosting that SwiftUI does not know what to do. So when transitioning the orange view will get the corner radius it is provided and will not animate this property from the original 60.0 to the new 0.0. As for the red view it will not animate this property from 60.0 to 0.0. The only thing it does is animate the size.

How can I teach SwiftUI to transition the corner radius accordingly? So both views mimic each others behavior and it will appear to be one view.

Comment: For the animation to work smoothly, the change has to be applied to the same View. So instead of using 2 views with if-else you need to make it a single View. Then change the corner effect using a ternary operator.

Comment: It's also what I want, I want the first view to animate from 60.0 to 0.0 and the other view from 0.0 to 60.0 to mimic the transition. But if I put RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: goFullScreen ? 0.0 : 60.0) on both views it will not go of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days, I finally came up with a solution that works.

```
//  Created by Mark van Wijnen on 19/08/2023.

import SwiftUI

public struct CornerRadiusKey: EnvironmentKey {
    public static let defaultValue: Double = 0
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var cornerRadius: Double {
        get { return self[CornerRadiusKey.self] }
        set { self[CornerRadiusKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct AnimatableRoundedRectangle: View {
    @Environment(\.cornerRadius) var cornerRadius: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    }
}

struct AnimatableRoundedRectangleModifier: ViewModifier, Animatable {
    var cornerRadius: Double
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { cornerRadius }
        set { cornerRadius = newValue }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .environment(\.cornerRadius, cornerRadius)
    }
}

extension AnyTransition {
    static func cornerRadius(identity: Double, active: Double) -> AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition.modifier(
            active: AnimatableRoundedRectangleModifier(cornerRadius: active),
            identity: AnimatableRoundedRectangleModifier(cornerRadius: identity)
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    @State private var isFullScreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !isFullScreen {
                ZStack {
                    AnimatableRoundedRectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "card", in: namespace)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
                .transition(.cornerRadius(identity: 60.0, active: 0.0))
            } else {
                ZStack {
                    AnimatableRoundedRectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "card", in: namespace)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .transition(.cornerRadius(identity: 0.0, active: 60.0))
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear, value: isFullScreen)
        .onTapGesture { isFullScreen.toggle() }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach, as shown in the example code. Seems to work for me.

```
 struct ContentView: View {
     @State private var goFullScreen = false
     
     var body: some View {
         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: goFullScreen ? 0 : 60.0)
             .fill(.orange)
             .frame(maxWidth: goFullScreen ? .infinity : 300,
                    maxHeight: goFullScreen ? .infinity : 300)
             .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: goFullScreen ? 0 : 60.0))
             .animation(.linear, value: goFullScreen)
             .onTapGesture {
                 goFullScreen.toggle()
             }
             .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
     }
 }
```

Comment: It works for me too, but I need this to happen between views. As if you click a photo in a photos scrollview and that photo pops out. Imagine the photo having corners and when you click it goes full screen without rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

Following from your comments, if you want the animation to happen when transitioning between two separate views then your best bet is to use a state variable for the corner radius. It's not perfect, but it's better than what you had before:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var namespace
    @State private var goFullScreen = false
    private static let roundedCornerRadius = CGFloat(60.0)
    @State private var cornerRadius = ContentView.roundedCornerRadius

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if goFullScreen == false {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
                    .fill(.orange)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "box", in: namespace, isSource: !goFullScreen)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .onAppear { cornerRadius = ContentView.roundedCornerRadius }
            } else {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
                    .fill(.orange)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "box", in: namespace, isSource: goFullScreen)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .onAppear { cornerRadius = 0 }
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear, value: goFullScreen)
        .animation(.linear, value: cornerRadius)
        .onTapGesture {
            goFullScreen.toggle()
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

---

*EDIT* Following up on your further comments:

> 1. Somehow the inserted view grows larger fasted, although we set the animation on linear. Both views should mimic the behavior and therefor no ghosting.

I suspect that this is because `matchedGeometryEffect` is scaling the view, so in absolute terms the radius sizes do not match. You can resolve this by dropping the use of matchedGeometryEffect and using a state variable for the size instead (just like the state variable for the corner radius). Use this state variable to control maxWidth and maxHeight.

> 2. If you reverse the animation the inserted view won't animate the corners.

If you mean, switching the if-else, then make sure cornerRadius is initialized with the correct value. You also need to change the flag `isSource` for the matchedGeometryEffect.

> 3. If you interrupt the animation and it grows large again the corners will stay rounded.

Yes, if you double tap while the animation is happening then the wrong radius may get left in effect. This can be resolved by adding onDisappear callbacks too.

Another way to implement the effect would be to avoid using a transition altogether. You can use opacity to control visibility and then use animations that exactly mimic each other. This allows changes to the corner radius and size to be animated smoothly. Not sure if it's practical for real-world use though.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var namespace
    @State private var goFullScreen = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
                .frame(maxWidth: goFullScreen ? .infinity : 300, maxHeight: goFullScreen ? .infinity : 300)
                .cornerRadius(goFullScreen ? 0 : 60)
                .opacity(goFullScreen ? 0 : 1)
            Color.orange
                .frame(maxWidth: goFullScreen ? .infinity : 300, maxHeight: goFullScreen ? .infinity : 300)
                .cornerRadius(goFullScreen ? 0 : 60)
                .opacity(goFullScreen ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .animation(.linear, value: goFullScreen)
        .onTapGesture {
            goFullScreen.toggle()
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually comes really close to the effect I am after! I only need to fine tune the opacity in the transition and I think we nailed it.

Comment: There are a couple of bugs I could find with this approach. 1. Somehow the inserted view grows larger fasted, although we set the animation on linear. Both views should mimic the behavior and therefor no ghosting. 2. If you reverse the animation the inserted view won't animate the corners. 3. If you interrupt the animation and it grows large again the corners will stay rounded.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var toggle: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: toggle ? 0 : 40)
        .fill(Color.red)
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1), value: toggle)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .padding()
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation{ toggle.toggle() }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This was the first step in my question. The question is regarding a transition between views. I should have clarified that.