# How get rotational transition effect in matchedGeometryEffect?

Tags: swiftui

When I want change the position of `Rectangle` vertically or horizontally. My `matchedGeometryEffect` works just fine, but when my position changes from vertical to horizontal or horizontal to vertical, I want rotation transition, but I cannot get that. Right now, I used scale but it did not solve the issue.

How to give rotation effect when the position change is vertical to horizontal or horizontal to vertical?

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myClass: MyClass = MyClass.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            MyView()
                .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
                .background(Color.red).cornerRadius(20.0)
            
            HStack {
                
                Button("top") {
                    myClass.position = .top
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("bottom") {
                    myClass.position = .bottom
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("left") {
                    myClass.position = .left
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("right") {
                    myClass.position = .right
                }
                
            }
            .frame(width: 300.0)
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

enum Position: String {
    case top, bottom, left, right
}

class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    static let shared: MyClass = MyClass()
    @Published var position: Position = Position.bottom
}



struct MyView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myClass: MyClass = MyClass.shared
    @Namespace var matchedGeometryEffectOfRectangle
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            switch myClass.position {
            case .top:
                
                VStack {
                    Color.blue.frame(height: 50.0).cornerRadius(10.0)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Rectangle", in: matchedGeometryEffectOfRectangle)
                        .transition(.scale(scale: 1, anchor: .center))
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            case .bottom:
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Color.blue.frame(height: 50.0).cornerRadius(10.0)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Rectangle", in: matchedGeometryEffectOfRectangle)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 1, anchor: .center))                }
                
            case .left:
                
                HStack {
                    Color.blue.frame(width: 50.0).cornerRadius(10.0)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Rectangle", in: matchedGeometryEffectOfRectangle)
                        .transition(.scale(scale: 1, anchor: .center))
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            case .right:
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Color.blue.frame(width: 50.0).cornerRadius(10.0)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Rectangle", in: matchedGeometryEffectOfRectangle)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 1, anchor: .center))                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .animation(.default, value: myClass.position)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.matchedGeometryEffect` it lets you smooth the change in dimensions when you transition from one view to another, but the default transitions do not include the possibility to apply a `rotationEffect` as well. So you have two options:

**1. Create a custom transition**

For an example of how this can be done, see the accepted answer to [How can I transition from a circle/rounded rectangle to a rectangle in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76937415/20386264)

**2. Apply changes to a single view**

If the transformation can be achieved by changing the modifiers on a single view then you can animate these changes any way you like and there are no transitions involved. This is probably the simpler and easier approach, if it feasible.

Here is how your example can be implemented in this way:

```swift
struct MyView: View {

    let barHeight = CGFloat(50)
    @StateObject var myClass: MyClass = MyClass.shared

    private var isHorizontal: Bool {
        myClass.position == .top || myClass.position == .bottom
    }

    private func xOffset(maxWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let result: CGFloat
        switch myClass.position {
        case .top, .bottom: result = 0
        case .left: result = (barHeight / 2) - (maxWidth / 2)
        case .right: result = (maxWidth / 2) - (barHeight / 2)
        }
        return result
    }

    private func yOffset(maxHeight: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let result: CGFloat
        switch myClass.position {
        case .top: result = 0
        case .left, .right: result = (maxHeight / 2) - (barHeight / 2)
        case .bottom: result = maxHeight - barHeight
        }
        return result
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.blue
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: barHeight)
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isHorizontal ? 0 : 90))
                .offset(
                    x: xOffset(maxWidth: proxy.size.width),
                    y: yOffset(maxHeight: proxy.size.height)
                )
        }
        .padding()
        .animation(.default, value: myClass.position)
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not wanted start working on single view and I wanted do this by transition, since you created the working code I am okay with it.